# How to find the exact link of a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I can view a PDF document from a website. But the URL is not an actual PDF document. The URL looks like:

```
http://www.maskingtheRealSiteName.com/reportpdf/type/dossier/pdfno/IND003212202
```

Thus the actual PDF document is embedded on the page.

How can I obtain  the actual .PDF link of this document?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Try <F12> then click on the "Network" tab. Go to (or refresh) the page where you can see the .pdf. Then click on the "filter" icon and type `.pdf`:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/i3WpR.png . Does the pdf link show up?

Comment: Thanks for reply Pace.... I do not have Chrome. Do we have similar workaround for Firefox or IE plz? Also, Do I have to install any extention of FF for that?

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because it is more browser related. It may be suitable on Super User however it could be duplicate as there are various questions regarding [finding out file url path](http://superuser.com/questions/854978/how-to-find-out-direct-url-address-of-a-file).

Comment: Why is this Off topic?  The Browser is how the communication happens between Client and a Website.  Why is offtopic that for Webmaster? SuperUser is more about PC.

Comment: If this is a restricted site that requires login (as your original question stated) then it shouldn't be possible to find the actual document. The actual document should not be publicly accessible. There might not be a file that ends `.pdf` either. This isn't something you can necessarily find out client-side. On the other hand, the link you have posted might already be the "actual .PDF link of this document".

Comment: Natasha, asking questions on how to find links isn't related to webmaster type of questions. That question is more like a question on where to find content. First answer that comes to mind is google. If the website has a contact form, use it and contact whoever is in charge of the content which is likely the webmaster. If however, you meant something totally different in your question, then you should reword it so we can all understand it better.

Comment: @NatashaSharmaakaNino I have edited your "Why is this off topic" comment to remove the personal attacks.   This site is not a place where we allow that.